# Returning N number of equally spaced items from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (available appointments). I may only return 5 results from the array, and when the array has > 5 results i want to equally, or as equally as possible space the results. My function below works, except when the array size is 8 or 9, given that it then calculates the largest step it can use to be 1, which results in no distribution when i have 9 items.

How do I modify this to make it somewhat equally spaced?

I considered just calculating a random and using that, but returning the items in the correct order is important. I.E. I can't return `[1] [4] [0] [2] [5]` - but i can return `[0] [2] [4] [8] [9]`

```
function getEquallySpacedItems(array) {
  if (array. Length <= 5) {
    return array; 
  }

  let step = Math.floor(array. Length / 5); // Calculate the step size
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += step) {
      result.push(array[i]); // Add every 'step'-th item to the result
  if (result. Length === 5) {
    break; // Stop if we have 5 items in the result
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "equally spaced"?

Comment: also this condition (that you use in 2 parts of your code) `if (array. Length <= 5) {` and `if (result. Length === 5) {` won't work because js is case sensitive. It's `length` not `Length`. This line also needs to be fixed `let step = Math.floor(arr. Length / 5);`

Comment: The simplest thing is to use floating point to compute the spacing then round the resulting index.

Comment: @JackA. Is correct. You just need to ensure that you don't use the same index twice. So remember the previous index, and if the new rounded index is the same, add 1 to it.

Comment: @Barmar True in general, but I believe that breaking out when the array size is less than or equal to the number of items to be returned will prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises in the question of 'equally spacing'. You *can't* equally space steps when it doesn't divide equally, there will always have to be jumps of different sizes.

The trick is you can approximate it. Consider this function:

```
function getEquallySpaced(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 5) {
    return arr;
  }

  let step = (arr.length - 1) / 4;

  let idx = 0;
  let res = [];
  for (let i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    res.push(arr[Math.round(idx)]);
    idx += step;
  }
  return res;
}
```

It's very similar to yours, with a few differences. `step` is kept as a fractional value. Each time it is accessed, it is rounded to the nearest index.

Also note `let step = (arr.length - 1) / 4`. This is because, for an array of length *n*, your first value will be index zero, and your last value with be index `4 * step_size`. This step value will cause you to always select the first and last elements, and then an average spacing of the ones in-between

Comment: Of course you can't equally space, that's why they said "as equally as possible"